# Android Internal Testing causes cache issues in Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

My goal is to replicate the TestFlight experience in Android:

1. Select beta-testers get invited
2. Every time I make a release, they are notified, and can upgrade.

To do this, I thought the analog was the "Internal Testing" track. However, I am coming across an issue, when it comes to updates. Here's the scenario:

1. User installs version 1
2. I release version 2

Problem 1: They are *not* notified of the new version
I would certainly have liked for a notification or an auto-update to have kicked off.

Problem 2: They see the old version in their Play Store
In order for them to get the latest version, I constantly have to ask them to clear their Play Store cache and storage, uninstall the app, and reinstall it again.

This feels like a bug.

I contacted Play Store, and they said...it works as intended?

[image: works as intended]

Is this true? If yes, what is the best way to quickly send updates to beta users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, I side-stepped this by using Firebase's App Distribution. It's much faster to deliver updates, and the experience to sign up beta testers is much better.